# Porting sort with lambda function to Python 3

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, lambda

I'm porting code from Python 2.7 to 3. 2to3 does not convert the following lines and can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

```
subpaths.sort(
    lambda x, y :
        int(pyx.unit.tocm(x.arclen() - y.arclen()) /
            math.fabs(pyx.unit.tocm(x.arclen() - y.arclen()))) )
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without knowing what `subpaths` is and what `x` and `y` are, it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: And yet it's answered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) method of a `list` requires a `key`, which is a function of just one argument. You need to convert your lambda function to a function of a single argument. There is a shortcut for that provided by [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key). Thus, what you probably need is:

```
import functools
subpaths.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(lambda x, y: ...))
```

Note that *if* I understand your code correctly, you can simply sort the list using the following key:

```
subpaths.sort(key=lambda x: pyx.unit.tocm(x.arclen()))
```

Comment: This solution is definetly the quickest to implement. But, if OP has time, IMO he should consider replacing `cmp` lambda with written from scratch `key` lambda, for improved efficency and readability.